# How to reload and animate specific cell in UITableView in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my application, I am using tableview with some rows. In each row I am displaying some part
    of text.In that row below text there is a Expandbtn. If we click that we will display the whole
    text.

For that I want to use reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: WithAnimation: method . I want to apply this 
 method  when I click Expandbtn in each cell.

I am using that above method for expanding text in cell. My Problem If I expand text in first 
 and go to  2nd cell it appears to be expanding and it is overlaping with first cell. 
If I scroll the table to the top, then first cell appears to be NOT Expanding.

Can Anyone Help me in this.
 Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Without code it's pretty impossible to find the problem

Answer (score 0):

Relating to "If I scroll the table to the top, then first cell appears to be NOT Expanding." It sounds like you are not dynamically determining the height of the rows.

Are you implementing the delegate method `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` in your NSTableViewController? If so, make sure you are returning a different value before and after you expand the row.